# Number of success runs of length T or more in N coin tosses

Tags: probability, bernoulli-numbers

We flip a coin, with success probability $p$, $N$ times. What is the distribution of the number of success runs of length at least $T$?

Comment: Start with this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test

Comment: geometric distribution?

Comment: @Pieter21 I have tried out a Markov chain formulation for the problem and tried to approximate the distribution with functions calculated at the steady state.

Answer (score 0):

In *A First Course in Probability* by Sheldon Ross, the author applies inclusion-exclusion formula to do this. First define event $E_i$ as the a sequence of n heads start at position i and followed by a tail. Then find the probability $P(\cup Ei)$.

Comment: I hope you are planning to add more to your Answer.  It seems to stop abruptly without describing the distribution of runs even in summary fashion.  Giving a reference is useful, but more useful would be to cite the specific page or section (qualified if necessary by edition) where this problem is addressed, and to quote or paraphrase the most relevant information to be found there.